# React native and .net CORE signalr API

Tags: react-native, signalr

Is it possible to connect react native app to .net Core signalr API? I've tried react-native-signalr but I get an error when negotiating with the API. I'm not sure if if that package is compatible with the newer .net Core Signalr.

Answer (score -2):

react-native-signalr package is for connecting to the older .net Framework Signalr API. For the newer .net CORE API then use this package instead: [@microsoft/signalr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/signalr) I've tested it and it works.